# lists get merged when formatting in vim

Tags: vim, text-formatting

I have a list like this

`- "some long line that needs to be broken into two lines"
- B
- C`

where A,B,C are placeholders for some text.

I attempt to format it with these options

`formatprg=par\ p0s0

let &l:formatlistpat='^\s*\(\d\+[\]:.)}\t ]\|[*-][\t ]\)\s*'

setlocal formatoptions=tcqjn`

I end up with this

`- A - B -C`

How do I get `vim` to simply format the lines like so?

`- "some long line that needs 
   to be broken into two lines"
- B
- C`

Answer (score 0):

set the text width

```
:set tw=30
```

then perform wordwrap on the paragraph (or other range)

```
gq}
```

produces

```
- "some long line that needs 
   to be broken into two lines"
- B
- C
```

Answer (score 0):

The `'formatlistpat'` only applies to the built-in Vim formatter. Once you define `'formatprg'`, this becomes meaningless. Your text doesn't seem to need the external formatter, so just drop it via `:setlocal formatprg=`.

Alternatively, you may want to find out how `par` can recognize the keep the list items.